# Database Research - which would be the best?

Tags: javascript, java, database, mongodb, nosql

We are developing a desktop application, the architecture of it is modular, there is a core level part and under it there are modules. The modules are written in Java and JavaScript code. 
We would like to use a database and we decided that a standalone database would be good for us which is:

- Cross-platform - Windows and Linux at least
- Portable - we have to install it together with the application, so one single setup would be the goal
- Has Java and JavaScript support. Each module has to be able to connect to the same database. Some of the modules are written in Java while some of them in JavaScript.
- NoSQL database

We would strongly prefer the MongoDB but on Windows, it has only installed as service installer. While this is a separate installer it does not fits for us. It's interesting for us that in the past it has still a zipped version...

First of all, I would like to ask if there is any way to make the MongoDB portable or to handle somehow our situation with it.
If the MongoDB do not fit for us, just because the portability what kind of database would fit our requirements?

Thank you so much, have a nice day,
                               Robert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean portable as in porting MongoDB to Windows or portable as in a portable version of MongoDB.  Here is a link for a "MongoDB-like" portable database:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-portable.   And here's the link to the community version of Mongo for Windows (with very specific requirements) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

If you wanted to port a version of MongoDB for your particular environment, it's open source so you could get the source and port it yourself.

I don't know about making some sort of portable version from the actual MongoDB distribution.  For that I'm sure you could check at mongodb.com.